# Iterating and modifying a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have code which has a dictionary of some words. The program intends to merge words.

That is if `word i` is in `word j` then merge the value of `dictionary[word i]` to `dictionary[word j]` and delete `dictionary[word i]`

```
for i in my_dict.keys():
   for j in my_dict.keys():
     if i!=j:
       if i in j:
          my_dict[j]+=my_dict[i]
          del my_dict[i]
       elif j in i:
          my_dict[i]+=my_dict[j]
          del my_dict[j]
```

Is this code valid?

Comment: Have you tried **testing it**?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: yes, I did some exceptions are thrown but the exception description was words from dictionary. I dont know whether its because of this code or not

Comment: So why don't you **provide the error traceback**? If you're getting errors, the answer is clearly *"No, this code is not valid."* Please edit the question to include a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code and data that actually recreates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not valid. There is no command `delete` in python for removing elements from dictionary. It is called `del`. You can delete an item from dictionary like this:

```
del your_dictionary['some_key']
```

However that is not very pythonic. You can refactor your code like this:

```
for i in my_dict.keys():
    for j in my_dict.keys():
        if i != j:
            if i in j:
                my_dict[j] += my_dict.pop(i)
            elif j in i:
                my_dict[i] += my_dict.pop(j)
```

`pop` is a dictionary method, which returns and removes an item from the dictionary.

The above code is a suggestion only regarding the merging (concatenating) of the values in the dictionary. The double `for` loop still looks ugly. But first make it work, later you can improve the quality of the code. I hope my example can help you.